# Super User Privilege to MySQL user

Tags: mysql

I am trying to give super user privilege to MySQL user by executing below command

`GRANT SUPER ON *.* TO indiaski_app@'localhost' IDENTIFIED BY 'appsocial'`

But I am getting following error -

> ## 1045 - Access denied for user 'indiaskinexam'@'localhost' (using password: YES)

Comment: I'm not sure, check the manual please, but doesn't your grant specify the user `indiaski_app` ? And you seem to get an access denied for user `indiaskinexam` which would be a different user. Or I forgot what the syntax is, but that looked odd to me

Answer (score 0):

You don't have access to database with the user 'indiaskinexam'. Your password is wrong, that means you can't execute SQL-statements.